# Where to define Rails select/radio options and how to store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, internationalization, radio-button

Where is the best place to define, and how should I store select/radio options for rails (and where to put translations)?

Right now I am defining a Hash within the model and storing the integer keys in the record.  I've also placed the translations as 'attributes' within the model translations as it seems to group them together well. ie

```
PHYSICAL_CONDITIONS = {
  1 => "activerecord.attributes.building.condition_excellent",
  2 => "activerecord.attributes.building.condition_good",
  3 => "activerecord.attributes.building.condition_average_for_age",
  4 => "activerecord.attributes.building.condition_fair",
  5 => "activerecord.attributes.building.condition_poor"
}.freeze
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I have dozens of fields with options and do not want to create separate tables for each either.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

- use varchar to store the answer ie 'excellent', 'good' from above.  This is actual meaningful data I can see in raw form vs numeric values.
- in my model have the options array.  The order is maintained and if I re-order them numbers don't matter:

  PHYSICAL_CONDITIONS = [
    :excellent,
    :good
  ]
- under the active record model translation have an options group for each set of options.  In the above case I call it `:physical_condition_options`.
- have each translation as a subset of that ie `excellent: "Excellent"`
- If I ever need to convert this to allow multiple selections (checkbox) on the model (happened a number of times), I just remove this subset and make it part of the model.  Migration is simpler instead of having to translate numeric values.
- have a helper translate those options when passing it to a field

  localized_options(Building::PHYSICAL_CONDITIONS,
            "activerecord.attributes.building.physical_condition_options.")

This seemed to be the best way to store the data and allow it to be easily translated.